# Connection error to oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have oracle Home ver 8.1 home installed on server machine ,and oracle database 11g express edition installed on client machine ,and im trying to connect to DB server using client 
using this command in sql command :

```
CONNECT username/password@DELL/service_names

but the error is 

ORA_12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

SQL>
```

so how to solve this problem 
*note: 2 machines on same subnet and listen process is DELL:1521   ESTABLISHED 
and the platform is windows

Comment: Does the service name you're supplying match what the listener is waiting for? `lsnrctl services` will show you that. I don't think Oracle actually support an 11g client with an 8i server, but the error makes it look like it might work anyway.

Comment: ya when i tried this command : connect username/password@ipAddr/service-names the error  shown that Exception: ora-03134: Connection to this Server Versions are no longer supported

Comment: Then you'll need to use a 10g client, or earlier. Or change the server to something a little more modern... why are you still using 8i at all?

Comment: because the DB 8i is not created by me ,and i want to create a connection to it,so another question ,can i upgrade my oracle DB from 8i to 11g without lose any single config or parameter ??????